# Can we port Ionic project to Tizen app?

Tags: ionic-framework, tizen-web-app

I want to know if we can port Ionic project to Tizen app.

As I know, Ionic using web Technology to build hybrid app. The same thing with tizen web app. 
Anybody can help me? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't seen Mentioning 'Tizen' platform in IONIC Framework website.

But there's a post on the Ionic Forum, still unanswered:

[Does cordova support Tizen?](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/does-cordova-support-tizen/73086)

So I guess the answer is "NO".

[Additional: you can check this post on tizen wiki: https://wiki.tizen.org/Cordova]